# Relation between trace of matrix $A^*A$ and invertibility of the matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Is there any relation between $\mathrm{tr}(A^*A)$ and invertibility of the matrix $A$? What information about the matrix $A$ does $A^*A$ gives ? 
I was confused about this when I came across the following statements:
Is it true that :

1. If $A$ is invertible, then $\mathrm{tr}(A^*A)$ is non zero.
2. If $|\mathrm{tr}(A^*A)|<n^2$, then $|a_{ij}|<1$ for some $i,j$
3. If $|\mathrm{tr}(A^*A)|=0$, then $A$ is a zero matrix.

Can someone help me with the answer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $A^*$ in context? Complex conjugate of $A$? Conjugate-transpose of $A$?

Comment: @RichardMartin [Conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose)

Comment: Hint: $\mathrm{tr}(A^*A)=\sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^2$. @RichardMartin No, it's not the "sum of squares", there is a modulus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a complex square matrix.

Since for a complex number $z = x + iy$ we have
$$
z^* z = (x - iy)(x + iy) = x^2 + y^2 = |z|^2,
\quad \text{where } |z| := \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
$$
Now we have
$$
A^* A =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1}^* & \ldots & a_{n,1}^* \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{1,n}^* & \ldots & a_{n,n}^*
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & \ldots & a_{1,n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n,1} & \ldots & a_{n,n}
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i,1} a_{i,1}^* & & \ast \\
& \ddots & \\
\ast & & \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i,n} a_{i,n}^*
\end{pmatrix}
$$
therefore we have $\operatorname{tr}(A^* A) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} |a_{i,j}|^2$

1. Let let $\operatorname{tr}(A^*A) = 0$ then $|a_{i,j}|=0$ for all so the $A$ is the zero matrix, so $\det(A)=0$, so it's not invertible, proving (1) by contraposition.
2. From the above sum formula for the trace, since all summands are positive, when the sum is smaller than $n^2$, which is the number of summands, one of the summands has to be smaller than 1.
3. Proven in (1).